# Sum of the total users of multiple AD groups

Tags: windows, powershell

I've been trying to get the total number of users in several active directory groups and so far I've gotten this put together:

```
$Groups = Get-Content -Path $someFile
foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    (Get-ADGroup $Group -Properties *).Member.Count
}
```

Of course, this spits out a number for each individual group, but I haven't come across any way of having ps add these numbers up and display the final total instead.

Comment: This is more-or-less trivial: Create a variable at the beginning of your script, and then add to it in your `ForEach` loop...

Comment: Do you want to count or skip duplicates (users that are members in several groups)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Definitely want to skip dupes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the count of unique members you could do something like this:

```
$script:cnt = 0
$Groups |
    Get-ADGroupMember |
    Select-Object -Expand DistinguishedName -Unique |
    ForEach-Object { $script:cnt++ }
```

If you want to resolve group members recursively (i.e. the members of nested groups as well) add `-Recursive` to `Get-ADGroupMember`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to an AD server to test this, but this should work by assigning the member count to a variable and adding the total of the current group to the variable, then output the total count when complete.

```
$Groups = Get-Content -Path
Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $totalusers += (Get-ADGroup $Group -Properties *).member.count
}
$totalusers
```